# Is this $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This question is related to [3-cocycle in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286199/3-cocycle-in-mathbbz-n-mathbbz)

Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

> Is $a(b-d+[c+d]-[b+c])$ equal to $0\mod n^2$?

Here the $[b+c]$ notation means $b+c\mod n$.

I cannot think of any counterexamples, yet I do not see why it is true.

Comment: @MichaelBurr My original question was how to show that the given formula is a cocycle, this question is about modular arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

The notation seems a little off because while there is a nice map from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z}$, it corresponds to multiplying by $n$, which might not be what you want.  I think that I know what you mean (so here's how I interpret your question).

Setup:
\begin{align}
x_1&=a+k_1n\\
x_2&=b+k_2n\\
x_3&=c+k_3n\\
x_4&=d+k_4n
\end{align}
where $0\leq a,b,c,d<n$ and the $k_i$'s are integers.

Is 
$$
x_1(x_2-x_4+[x_3+x_4]-[x_2+x_3])\equiv 0\pmod{n^2}?
$$
Now, we replace
\begin{align}
[x_3+x_4]&=x_3+x_4+k_5n\\
[x_2+x_3]&=x_2+x_3+k_6n\\
\end{align}
since reducing modulo $n$ means subtracting some multiple of $n$ (here $k_i$ is also an integer).  Therefore, we get that the original equation reduces to:

\begin{align}
x_1(x_2-x_4+[x_3+x_4]-[x_2+x_3])&=
x_1(x_2-x_4+x_3+x_4+k_5n-x_2-x_3-k_6n)\\
&=x_1(k_5n-k_6n)\\
&=a(k_5-k_6)n+k_1(k_5-k_6)n^2\equiv a(k_5-k_6)n\pmod{n^2}.
\end{align}

This suggests that you claim is not true.  If we can choose $a$ not a multiple of $n$, say $a=1=x_1$, $x_2=n-1$, $x_3=1$, and $x_4=1$.  Suppose that $n>2$.  Then $[x_3+x_4]=[2]=2$, $[x_2+x_3]=n=0$.  Then,
$$
x_1(x_2-x_4+[x_3+x_4]-[x_2+x_3])=1((n-1)-1+2-0)=n
$$
which is not a multiple of $n^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you take a look at the link in my question? Because from what I explain there, it should be $0\mod n^2$. What is going wrong?